# How do you calculate the variance on a weighted mean?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

How do I calculate a variance for the weighted mean value in the below program?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
$Path = Append[$Path, "c:"]
grades = OpenRead["grades.dat"]
data = ReadList[grades, {Number, Number}]
Close[grades]
w = 1/(data[[All, 2]]^2) // N
data2 = data[[All, 1]] // N
wd = WeightedData[data2, w]
```

Comment: why not `Variance[wd]`?

Comment: @kglr I believe that gives the sample variance, not the variance of the (weighted) mean

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use this variance definition.

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_chi-squared_statistic

*The unbiased weighted estimator of the sample variance can be computed as follows:*

[image]

where

[image]

**Example**

```
x = {1.21, 2.24, 1.2, 2.39, 1.1, 1.45, 2.29, 2.33, 1.13, 2.39};
w = {0.000977517, 0.00195503, 0.00391007, 0.00782014, 0.0156403,
   0.0312805, 0.0625611, 0.125122, 0.250244, 0.500489};
Total[w]
```

> ```
> 1.
> ```

```
w = 2 w; (* denormalise the weights to check normalisation is working *)
n = Length[x];

mu = Sum[w[[i]]*x[[i]], {i, 1, n}]/Sum[w[[i]], {i, 1, n}];

var = (Sum[w[[i]], {i, 1, n}]*
    Sum[w[[i]]*(x[[i]] - Sum[w[[i]]*x[[i]], {i, 1, n}]/
          Sum[w[[i]], {i, 1, n}])^2, {i, 1, n}])/
  (Sum[w[[i]], {i, 1, n}]^2 - Sum[w[[i]]^2, {i, 1, n}]);

wd = WeightedData[x, w];

Mean[wd] == mu
Variance[wd] == var
```

> ```
> True
> True
> ```

Answer (score 5):

```
SeedRandom[1]
dt = RandomInteger[10, 10];
wt = RandomInteger[10, 10];
wd = WeightedData[dt, wt];

Mean @ wd
```

> 80/33

```
Variance @ wd
```

> 4357/441

Verifying the formula in Chris Degnen's answer:

```
normalizedweights = Normalize[wt, Total];

mean = normalizedweights.dt
```

> 80/33

```
variance = (1/(1 - Total[normalizedweights^2])) normalizedweights .(dt - mean)^2
```

> 4357/441

Comment: Nice contraction of the formula.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be a random variable with a given distribution, and fix a sample size $n$.  Let $\bar X$ be the random variable representing the mean of a sample of size $n$.  If $\mathop{\text{Var}} (X)$ is the variance of $X$,
the variance of the mean, which is the variance of the distribution of sample means, is given by
$$\mathop{\text{Var}} (\bar X) = \mathop{\text{Var}}(X)\,/\,n\;.$$
Given one sample `wd`, with a point estimate for $\mathop{\text{Var}} (X)$ given by

```
Variance[wd]
```

then the variance of the mean could be estimated with

```
Variance[wd] / n
```

where `n` is sample size.  It's unclear to me whether the sample size is the same as `Length[data2]`, or the weighted data `wd` represents an [`EmpiricalDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmpiricalDistribution.html) from which samples of another size are to be drawn.

Comment: +1 This is the right answer.  All of the others give the estimate of the variance of the sample values when the question (whether intended or not) is about the variance of the estimator of the sample mean given that one has weighted data (as mentioned by @Valerio).

Answer (score 0):

The weighted mean can alternatively be written as

```
wd=data2.(w/Total[w])
```

the variance follows to

```
var=(data2-wd)^2.(w/Total[w])
```