Alternative Methods to Calculate Expected Value and Variance of Discrete Random Variables
discrete random variable:



Draw a list
Clear["`*"]
distTable = {{\[Xi], 0, 0.8, 1.6, 2.4, 3}, {P, 0.8, 0.1, 0.06, 0.03, 
    0.01}};
grid = Grid[distTable, Alignment -> Center, Dividers -> All]



Calculate the expected value and variance.
values = {0, 0.8, 1.6, 2.4, 3};
probabilities = {0.8, 0.1, 0.06, 0.03, 0.01};
expectation = 
 Sum[values[[i]]*probabilities[[i]], {i, Length[values]}]
variance = 
 Sum[(probabilities[[i]]*(values[[i]] - expectation)^2), {i, 
   Length[values]}]




Or this method:
values = {0, 0.8, 1.6, 2.4, 3};
probabilities = {0.8, 0.1, 0.06, 0.03, 0.01};
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[probabilities -> values];
mean = Mean[dist]
variance = Variance[dist]



Finally:Draw a table for a discrete random variable and calculate its expected value and variance in one time.
values = {0, 0.8, 1.6, 2.4, 3};
probabilities = {0.8, 0.1, 0.06, 0.03, 0.01};
distTable = {{\[Xi], ## & @@ values}, {P, ## & @@ probabilities}};
grid = Grid[distTable, Alignment -> Center, Dividers -> All]
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[probabilities -> values];
mean = Mean[dist]
variance = Variance[dist]

Or
values = {0, 0.8, 1.6, 2.4, 3};
probabilities = {0.8, 0.1, 0.06, 0.03, 0.01};
distTable = {{\[Xi], Sequence @@ values}, {P, 
    Sequence @@ probabilities}};
grid = Grid[distTable, Alignment -> Center, Dividers -> All]
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[probabilities -> values];
mean = Mean[dist]
variance = Variance[dist]



-1 for asking multiple questions in one post and not searching: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/255564/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/232809/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/165330/1871

And https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237615/1871

Use Dot
$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

(distTable = {{\[Xi], 0, 0.8, 1.6, 2.4, 3}, {P, 0.8, 0.1, 0.06, 0.03, 
     0.01}}) //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &


{values, probabilities} = Rest /@ distTable;

expectation = values . probabilities

(* 0.278 *)

variance = probabilities . (values - expectation)^2

(* 0.403116 *)


Transform the data into WeightedData:
values = {0, 0.8, 1.6, 2.4, 3};
probabilities = {0.8, 0.1, 0.06, 0.03, 0.01};

data = WeightedData[values, probabilities]

Mean@data
Variance@data


How to adjust Variance@data to 0.403116?

@cvgmt See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237615/1871 (Don't miss the comments. )
